# How can I install applications, share files on a remote computer?

Tags: networking, remote

My friend and I are both using ubuntu 12.04, however we live in different places.

We want to access each other's computer through internet. How can we do that?

For example, if I want to install a program to my friend's computer-by using my computer, is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to actually use Remote Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14484/how-to-actually-use-remote-desktop)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remote Desktop advice](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12623/remote-desktop-advice)

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with the command-line, you could just use `SSH` to get to his box and install stuff with `apt-get` ?

Basically you need to

- run the `sshd` (ssh daemon) on the target computer
- have the router route your traffic (port 22 is the default port)
- have access (username/password) to the machine
- use `ssh the.target.ip (-p port)` to gain access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use TeamViewer , for example.
You have to have it installed on both computers, after which you can access his desktop and he can access yours.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I'm trying it now. If it works, I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Vixxo.  To be more helpful to the OP maybe you can expand your answer, to share the capabilities of teamviewer, instructions how to install etc